# 3-Phase BLDC Motor Brake

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, three-phase

I want to be able to stop my motor instantly. When I am doing that with a single-phase motor, I just pull the phase to the ground and the motor instantly stops. Am I supposed to do the same with 3-phase motors?

Comment: There is nothing "instant" when inertia is involved. What you want is maximum braking force and yes, that's done in the same way with the same danger of damaging stuff.

Comment: But if I want to reverse the direction of my motor, I would want my motor to stop instantly in the time I change the direction.

Comment: The motor will stop if you short two or all three phases together. But if your motor controller is capable of doing torque control the best option will be to apply negative torque until it stops. That will stop it faster than shorting the phases together.